# Amazon S3 - add local computer to list of allowed referers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket policy in place (below) that only allows access to S3 from our remote website (to prevent hotlinking).  I'd like to also be able to access the files when working from our local computer.  I've tried adding my ip address, local ip, and localhost to aws:Referer but that hasn't worked.

For the task I'm trying to accomplish, I'd like to be able to directly access the files in my browser using the direct link: [https://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[filename]](https://s3.amazonaws.com/%5bbucket%5d/%5bfilename%5d)

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http referer policy example",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allow get requests referred by www.mysite.com and mysite.com",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[bucketname]/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://www.[mysite].com/*",
                    "http://192.168.1.6/*",
                    "http://foundwaves.com/*",
                    "http://[ip]/*",
                    "http://localhost/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Explicit deny to ensure requests are allowed only from specific referer.",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foundwaves/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://www.[mysite].com/*",
                    "http://192.168.1.6/*",
                    "http://foundwaves.com/*",
                    "http://[ip]/*",
                    "http://localhost/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Does your computer's IP address look like 192.168.x.x or 172.16x.x.x or 10.x.x.x ?

Comment: I'm on Mac OSX Mavericks.  Computer's ip looks like 192.168.x.x from Network tab in System Preferences.  When I do "what's my ip" from a browser it shows up as 50.x.x.x, which I also tried adding.

Comment: For the task I'm trying to accomplish, I'd like to be able to directly access the files in my browser using direct link: https://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[filename]

Comment: The `192.168.x.x` address is a private address only used internally on your LAN (and thus it is not visible by external services), the `50.x.x.x` is the one S3 will see.

Comment: I already tried the 50.x.x.x but it didn't work....

Comment: Sorry I partly misread your question - the thing is that you are checking on `aws:Referer` which in case of direct access obviously isn't set.  You will need a condition like `"Condition": {"IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "50.x.x.x/32"}}`, however that instruction would be nullified by the explicit deny you have as last rule and I am unsure how to solve that without eliminating the last rule...

Comment: Take a look on the following examples http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html